# Django : IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, mysql, django

Getting exception :

```
IndexError django.db.models.sql.compiler in apply_converters

IndexError: list index out of range in djagno queryset
```

I am doing this

```
object =Info.objects.get(is_active=False,device_id=device_id)
```

here device_id  is long text type in database schema and it is indexed

```
object =Info.objects.get(is_active=False,device_id=device_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with .first() and it would be like:

```
object = Info.objects.filter(is_active=False, device_id=device_id).first()
```

Comment: don't want to use filter , as there will always be single row

Comment: Django under .get() method is using filter anyway, and then call result[0], it's not a big deal. You can also try with get_object_or_404, it will raise 404 when object is not found.

Comment: i want to know why this error is there in first place

Answer (score 1):

You are using `get` method to fetch object.

Given query

```
object =Info.objects.get(is_active=False,device_id=device_id)
```

In this, **device_id** or **is_active** matching query might not be exist.

either you can use **try, except** method in **get**.

```
try:
    object =Info.objects.get(is_active=False,device_id=device_id)
except:
    object = None
```

or You have to use **filter** method

```
object =Info.objects.filter(is_active=False,device_id=device_id)[0]
```

OR

```
object =Info.objects.filter(is_active=False,device_id=device_id).first()
```

**filter** query will result None if query is not fetching data. Will not throw error for conditions not matching case.

Comment: don't want to use filter , as there will always be single row

Comment: If its single object, you must use try execpt handler.

Comment: i want to know why this error is there in first place